# How can I set the metaclass when calling `type`?

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I am trying to solve a metaclass conflict:

```py
>>> class A(B, C):
...   pass
...
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

In order to do so, I want to set the metaclass of the class that I'm creating with the `type` builtin function. In a class statement I'd do it like this:

```py
def merged(*parents):
  return type("meta", tuple(type(p) for p in parents), {})

class A(B, C, metaclass=merged(B, C)):
  pass
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

> Keyword arguments provided to the three argument form are passed to the appropriate metaclass machinery (usually `__init_subclass__()`) in the same way that keywords in a class definition (**besides metaclass**) would.

And indeed, the following still raises the same `TypeError`:

```py
def merged(*parents)
A = type("A", (B, C), {}, metaclass=merged(B, C))
```

How then can I pass the metaclass?

Comment: What exactly does _"trying to prevent a case of metaclass confusion"_ mean? And when you say _"doesn't work"_ what specifically happens, give a [mre] - if there's an error, for example, that's what the next person is likely to be searching for.

Comment: I'll include a reference that explains metaclass confusion, and include the typical TypeError that that raises :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had stuck the term 'metaclass confusion' in my head after seing it float around in ethereal references I cannot find anymore, so I've adapted it to 'metaclass conflict' as seen in the error statement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` is itself a metaclass - so you can't simply pass another metaclass as any argument to it. The equivalent of `type` in your example is the `merged` class as well - so, if one doesn't want to (and indeed, one should not) want to hardcode a `class` statement block just to make use of the `merged` metaclass, this is acceptable:

```
# build a merged metaclass of both B and C:

merged = type("merged_metaclass", (type(B), type(C)), {})

# instead of 
# A = type("A", (B, C), {}, metaclass=merged(B, C))
# write:
A = merged("A", (B, C), {})
```

In time: not that this is only possible if the metaclasses of both B and C are friendly and written in a way they themselves can be composed. That is usually the case for well behaved metaclasses in high profile projects, but *not* when the metaclasses are built in projects designed to be single-shot. Depending on the nature of the metaclasses, they may not be composable at all. In particular, both, if implementing a `__new__` method, should be using `super().__new__(...)` inside it, and not directly `type.__new__(...)`  .  (If just one of those is using `super()` you can try to put it first in the bases tuple- but things are not looking good at this point)

However, there are more situations and corner cases when using metaclasses - for example, if any of your metaclasses is to implement a custom `__prepare__` method that should be called.

Due to that, back in Python 3.3, a couple calls where added to the `types` stdlib module to allow one to have all the options available for creating a new in a imperative programmatic model, in contrast with the declarative use of the `class` statement. Always keep in mind that for the majority of cases, calling the new metaclass directly, as above, is all that is needed.

The equivalent to `type`, but allowing one to pass an explicit metaclass is not straightforward.  The call `types.new_class(name, bases=(), exec_body=...)` needs that the exec_body receives a callable that will be responsible for updating the class namespace with the class components (methods and attributes) - and it does not accept a dictionary (or other mapping) passed directly.

If no metaclass have a custom `__prepare__` that will return a non-standard mapping, the call can be done like this:

```
import types
...
merged = ...


a_namespace = {"clsattr": "example"} 

A = types.new_class(name, (B, C), kwds={"metaclass": merged}, exec_body= lambda ns: ns.update(a_namespace))
```

Another possible call is `type.prepare_class` that will return the correct metaclass and the appropriate namespace (as created by the selected `__prepare__`) method to be used - after populating the namespace, one calls the returned metaclass as above:

```
import types
...
merged = ...


metaclass, namespace, kwds = types.prepare_class("A", (B, C), kwds={"metaclass": merged})

# example of custom class A attribute insertion: 
namespace["clsattr"] = "example"

A = metaclass("A", (B, C), namespace, **kwds)
```

Answer (score 0):

`object` is the base class for classes, and `type` is the baseclass of metaclasses. This means that objects that inherit from `object` will produce instances when called, and objects that inherit from `type` will produce classes when called.

Your `merged` function is already taking the `object`-inheriting classes and by inspecting with the 1 argument form of `type`, using their `type`-inheriting metaclass. That means that the type produced from `merged` is itself a metaclass; obviously, because you then pass it to `metaclass=`!

In conclusion, you can call this metaclass, just like you would call `type`, to produce your class of metaclass `merged(B, C)`:

```py
metaA = merged(B, C)
A = metaA("A", (B, C), {})
```